# <_CustomFiles> element not recognized in .pubxml

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, publish, pubxml

I'm trying to include a file in an ASP.NET filesystem publish that's not included in the solution (it's autogenerated from a post-build script).  According to [these instructions](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files), I should be able to add a reference to the file in my `.pubxml` definition using the `<_CustomFiles>` element.  Here's what my `.pubxml` file looks like:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>(publish URL here)</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="scripts\app.min.js" />

      <FilesForPackagingFromProject  Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>Extra Files\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The second `<PropertyGroup>` and the `<Target>` elements were added by me.

However, Visual Studio isn't recognizing the `<_CustomFiles>` element and the file isn't being included in the publish.  Notice the green squiggly line underneath the element:

[image]

When I hover over it, the following error message is shown:

```
The element 'ItemGroup' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid child element '_CustomFiles' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'
```

Why is this element not recognized by Visual Studio?  What do I need to change in order to include this file in my filesystem publish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out.  I misunderstood the purpose of the `<_CustomFiles>` element.  It seems this is a custom element (i.e. not part of the XML schema, hence the VS warning) used to pass information to the `<FilesForPackaginFromProject>` element below it.

It turns out this method *was* working for me, I was simply using the relative paths incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Nathan, where were you going wrong with the relative paths? I'm facing similar troubles!